# How to get the right document from meters DB based on timestamp?

Tags: marklogic

I do not want to send `REST` calls due to some reasons. I need to get the documents from `meters DB` using `XQuery`. 
`Scenario 1 :` Let's say I want to know the database related history information where `start date and end date is same` at `minute` basis. ex. `2018-02-02 15:32`. How can I identify the right `URI of databases-raw.xml` ?
Let's keep it to scenario 1 for now.

Answer (score 0):

For details you can look at the xquery code that implements the REST endpoint, it is in the MarkLogic install Modules directory.

In general, there are 2 ways, either by searching based on the document content (it is indexed appropriately) or by creative filtering of the URI's.
Usually it takes searching.

The URI's are all consistantly named:

```
/<cluster-id>/<group-id>/<host-id>/<timestamp>/xxxxx-xxx.xml
```

The timestamps is in **epoch** Unix timestamp 32-bit. The timestamps are rounded such that they align with the 'period-start-time'.
Whereas the actual exact time the document was inserted is in the create-date element.

When searching use the period-start-time as that is consistent throughout the meters files.  Note: the meters files are designed so they can share the same database as other meters files from different clusters, none of which has to be 'the current cluster'.  This allows you to offload the Meters data as xml files into another MarkLogic instance such as your local host.

Comment: are you sure the timestamp aligns with 'period-start-date' ? I think it aligns with 'end-date' in case of raw periods. Could you confirm on this ?

Comment: Yes your correct, the document URI timestamp corresponds to the datetime the document was written, hence would be the end time, rounded to the period